# Изменение стилей блока с помощью javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, функции

Есть два блока, надо сделать функцию на javascript,
чтобы по нажатию на кнопку 1 блок принял стиль `display: block;`,
а второй `display:none;`

Comment: А проблема в чём? И пример HTML не помешает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, нужна такая переключалка?

```js
[...document.getElementsByClassName('div')].forEach((s, i) => {
  s.addEventListener('click', function() {
    [...document.getElementsByClassName('div')].forEach((s, i) => {
      document.getElementsByClassName('div')[i].style.display = 'block';
    })
    s.style.display = 'none';

  })
})
```

```html
<div class="div">Первый блок</div>
<div class="div">Второй блок</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById('div1').style = "display: block";
  document.getElementById('div2').style = "display: none";
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">Первый блок</div>
<div id="div2">Второй блок</div>
<button onclick="myFunction()">click</button>
```